# Move a directory in remote server to another location in the same remote server using jsch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using JSCH API to connect to remote server through sftp.
I need to move a directory present in the remote server from  location A to location B.
It looks like the method **channelsftp.put(src,dest)** allows to move only a file and not the directory.

Can someone please explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the rename command, it would move the file or directory and delete it from the original place.

sftpChannel.rename(oldFile, newFile);

Don't use this method, if you want to keep the original directory/file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: to avoid errors, first check that the file oldFile  doesn't exist in newFile: sftpChannel.rm(newFile) and then sftpChannel.rename(oldFile, newFile);