# How to move CSV file in FTP server one folder to another?

Tags: java, io, sftp

When i am trying to move file from fileDirectory1 to fileDirectory2 .. Is there any way to move or copy that file from one path to another in one FTP server.Please anyone can help me.

Here is my sample code:

```
                      String existingfile = file.getFilename();
                        String newfile =file.getFilename();
                        String fileDirectory1 = clients.getFtpFolder() + "/" + "unprocessed" + "/";
                        String fileDirectory2 = clients.getFtpFolder() + "/" + "processed" + "/";
                        sftpChannel.cd(fileDirectory1);
                        if (sftpChannel.get(newfile) != null){
                            sftpChannel.rename(fileDirectory1 + newfile , 
                                    fileDirectory2 + newfile );
                            sftpChannel.cd(fileDirectory2);
                            sftpChannel.rm(existingfile );
                        }
```

Console:

```
Caused by:2: No such file
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
```

I have tried [How to move file from directory A to directory B in remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050045/how-to-move-file-from-directory-a-to-directory-b-in-remote-server)

[Move a directory in remote server to another location in the same remote server using jsch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277218/move-a-directory-in-remote-server-to-another-location-in-the-same-remote-server)

Comment: Do you have write permissions in the source and destination folders ?

Comment: Yes i have permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ChannelSftp#rename`:

```
sftpChannel.rename(oldPath, newPath);
```

Note that `oldPath` and `newPath` can be a relative path to your current remote working directory or a absolute remote path.

**Edited:**

Seems you use `sftpChannel.cd(fileDirectory1)` to change your working directory to `fileDirectory1` and suppose `newfile` is inside that directory, you can have a try with something like

```
sftpChannel.rename(filename, destFilePath);
```

Note that `filename` is a file name and `destFilePath` is the remote file path of the destination. I have used it before and it works fine.

You code will be something like:

```
sftpChannel.rename(newfile, fileDirectory2 + newfile);
```

in your code. Hope this can help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277218/move-a-directory-in-remote-server-to-another-location-in-the-same-remote-server

Comment: not work means exception occurs? the file do not move to remote path? or something other else?

Comment: Please have a try with my updated answer see whether can help